# Can't delete face Maya

Tags: maya, 3d-modeling

So here is my model (bed sheets). I have an extra face right below it and I cannot delete it. I made it bigger for you guys but at first it was really small. I have no idea how that geometry got there. I used nCloth for the bed sheets and it was my first time using it, maybe that's where I screwed up.

I tried to separate the faces for the sheets and create a new object but I received that message: // Error: line 0: sheets has only one piece. Ignored.

[image]

Comment: Those who think this question does not belong here should [vote for this new stack proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-computer-graphics) (vote only on questions that have 9 or less upvotes because each user get only 5 votes).